# Why am I running 3.2.0-32?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, xubuntu, versions

I am running xubuntu 12.04 LTS  :

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

When I do

```
uname -a
```

I have :

```
Linux tolede 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

According to the release notes, it should be 3.5.0.23-35 :

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/Xubuntu

I did the automatic update a few days ago.

Why am I not running the lastest version?

Comment: I intent to delete this question and ask another one.

Answer (score 3):

Automatic updates to 12.04.2 won't upgrade to the 3.5.x kernel.

As it says in the article you linked:

> For more information regarding the 12.04.2 LTS Hardware Enablement Stack, please refer to:
>
> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack

In that article, we can see:

> ... Only those installing from the 12.04.2 media will automatically receive a newer hardware enablement stack by default...
>
> Anyone wishing to opt into the hardware enablement stack for Precise may do so by running following command which will install the linux-generic-lts-quantal and xserver-xorg-lts-quantal packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
> ```